# Crystal reports date functions and formula

Tags: date, crystal-reports, formula

I'm not even sure how to start writing this logic. I have help desk issues in a SQL database with a create date and a resolved date columns. I'm trying to display only the records in which their create date is 14 days or less than the resolved date. Right now the report prompts for the start date and end date. Now I want to modify it. How do I write this logic and in which section of the formula builder?  I'm using CR 2011 Standard.

Comment: Hi Gina, Could you kindly share the database table you are using with data types ? Then it will be easy for us to suggest an answer.

Comment: Not sure how to share a database table.  
Table - ISSUES
Field IS_CREATE_DATETIME: Number
Field - IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME: Number

There are two parameters fields that prompt:
?StartDate
?EndDate

I would like the report to prompt for an ?EndDate and then calculate back 14 business days and not include weekends.  So the ?StartDate really isn't relevant because it will depend on the ?EndDate which is the resolved date.